# Convert nested json string to custom object

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am using this code to deserialize json string into an object:

```
var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LdapAccount>(result.ToString());
```

I am getting this error:

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'mail', line 8, position 12.

I know it is because of the nesting in the json, but not sure how to resolve.  I only care about the properties in my custom class.

Json string:

```
{
  "DN": "cn=jdoe,ou=test,dc=foo,dc=com",
  "objectClass": [
    "inetOrgPerson",
    "organizationalPerson",
    "person"
  ],
  "mail": [
    "john.doe@foo.com"
  ],
  "sn": [
    "Doe"
  ],
  "givenName": [
    "John"
  ],
  "uid": [
    "jdoe"
  ],
  "cn": [
    "jdoe"
  ],
  "userPassword": [
    "xxx"
  ]
}
```

My class:

```
public class Account
    {
        public string CID { get; set; }            
        public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string mail { get; set; }
        public string uid { get; set; }
        public string userPassword { get; set; }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... the JSON notation is expecting an array or list of strings, but you have it expecting a single string.

If you are using `JSON.NET`, you could change it like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public string CID { get; set; }            
    public string jsonrpc { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> mail { get; set; }
    public List<string> uid { get; set; }
    public List<string> userPassword { get; set; }            
}
```

Should work better...

BTW, the properties `CID`, `jsonrpc` `id` do not have corresponding fields in the JSON itself. So expect these to not get populated.

Answer (score 1):

Some name/value pairs in your JSON file like mail, uid, userpassword are defined as `array`.
http://json.org/

Howerver, the same name properties in `Account` class are not array or List. If you change your JSON file like this, the deserialization will work.

```
{
  "DN": "cn=jdoe,ou=test,dc=foo,dc=com",
  "objectClass": [
    "inetOrgPerson",
    "organizationalPerson",
    "person"
  ],
  "mail": "john.doe@foo.com",
  "sn": "Doe",
  "givenName": "John",
  "uid": "jdoe",
  "cn": "jdoe",
  "userPassword": "xxx"
}
```